How to Detect an ArUco Marker from a 3D Model in Unity for HoloLens 2?
I've seen many repositories on how to detect physical ArUco or QR markers using the HoloLens 2 camera. However, in my current project, I receive an OBJ file and a corresponding texture file. When I view the 3D object in Blender, I notice a marker attached to it. I need to detect this marker from the OBJ file. Since I can't use the HoloLens 2's main camera to detect it, is there a way to detect an ArUco marker from the 3D model that I uploaded in Unity? I would greatly appreciate any related information!
I have tried using OpenCV to detect the marker from the texture file, and then perform UV mapping to locate the marker on the 3D object. However, the texture file often contains only a partial marker, so this method does not always work.
